# Access: CrossTab Query Increase Data Text 'length'?

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access, text, string-length

I currently have a pressing problem.

I have a mysql back-end MSAccess front-end. I've just normalized my database as the old structure required too much maintenance and was in theory bad design.

I recently found the CrossTab Query and found it a godsend.

However one small issue... just came to my attention. One of the columns displays a text field. This text field is a mysql "TEXT" Datatype with no set Length.

It seems that the CrossTab rendering of these text field however do have a set length.

Is there a way to increase the CrossTab's Text set length? I cannot seem to find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fairly sure you are limited to 255 characters in a crosstab, however, you may be able to join a saved crosstab to a table or query to reference the full text. You can with Access on a Jet/ACE backend, but I have not tested with MySQL.

Comment: This is one of those comments that make me say: Why didn't I think of that. Thanks Remou